# aiogram How to delete past bot message when sending a new one?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

How to delete past bot message when sending a new one?

After '/start', the user sees a greeting and several InlineKeyboardButtons, after selecting the one he needs, he sees a new message. How can I delete a past message (greeting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off editing this message instead of adding a new one and deleting the old one - improves user experience as there will be no flickering (messages added and deleted).

Use `editMessageText`
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext

However, if you still want to delete a message, you need to know it's message id.
Use this `deleteMessage`
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage